# How to install Yarn v1 and Yarn v2 on the same machine so they can be used interchangelby between projects?

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm running a couple of projects that make use of Yarn v1 that will not be upgraded to Yarn v2 anytime soon for many reasons (CI being one of them). However, I would like to use Yarn v2 for new projects.

Is there a sane way to have both Yarn v1 and Yarn v2 installed on one machine so they can be used interchangebly between projects?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We recommend using Yarn 1 as global so as to avoid possible backward compatibility issues (for example later versions renamed some options and settings). You then have two options:

- You can use `yarn policies set-version berry` on a per-project basis; it will install the very latest Yarn releases in the
  `.yarn/releases` folder, which you can then add to your repository. [Docs for `yarn policies`](https://legacy.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/policies/).
- Or you can add a `"packageManager": "yarn@3.2.0"` field to your `package.json` file and run `corepack enable`. This will use the [Corepack](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html) tool to setup your system in such a way that any `yarn` commands will use the exact version you configured for the active project.

This keeps the risks to a minimum and allows you to migrate when you feel ready.