# Using "m1-medium" not recognized as valid by EAS

Tags: expo, eas

When I follow [these instructions](https://blog.expo.dev/m1-workers-on-eas-build-dcaa2c1333ad) on an M2 MBA using Expo SDK 47.0.13 and EAS CLI 3.5.2 (darwin-arm64) I get

```
    InvalidEasJsonError: eas.json is not valid.
    - "build.dev-hardware.resourceClass" must be one of [default, medium]
```

which seems like a direct contradiction of those instructions. Why isn't the specified value (`m1-medium`) recognized as valid?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by updating my eas-cli on global level. In my situation I tried updating it with

```
npm install -g eas-cli
```

If you've used a different package manager like I did to install eas-cli earlier, you may need to run the command accordingly. In my case it was

```
yarn global add eas-cli
```

Also, it's maybe worth checking if in your **eas.json** file you have any setting related to the cli version like this:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.3.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I remembered that when this was happening, whenever I ran `eas build` the console printed a message like this:

[image]

I ran the suggested npm install command, but message was still prompted, which led me to believe that yarn was in control of the version of the eas-cli that executes `eas build`.
This is why I ran yarn global add, which fixed the issue.

---

Comment: Are you saying I need Yarn project at the root? Currently I don't have one there, just some `npm -g` installed tools. And the version of Yarn there is ([has to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934413/656912)) [1.22.19](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/yarn-error-fatal-on-executing-jupyterlab/15777/10?u=orome) and not 3.2.3 (used in my projects).

Comment: No. Especially if you do not use Yarn for the current project. I just found an expo forum thread that explains how expo-cli version could be conflicting with the one listed as installed from yarn. Solutions depend on what suits you best: uninstall expo-cli from yarn or just upgrade it in yarn as I did. [Here is the link to the forum](https://forums.expo.dev/t/cant-upgrade-to-the-lastest-expo-cli-3-19-2/36764)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when tried to start script from the package.json

```
yarn build:ios
```

Run command directly in the terminal works properly

```
eas build --profile dev --platform ios
```