# Why am I told to install versioned Expo CLI when it's already installed?

Tags: npm, expo, yarnpkg, eas, yarnpkg-v2

When I run

```
expo-cli doctor
```

I get

```
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
```

But when I run

```
yarn expo doctor
```

I get

```
expo doctor is not supported in the local CLI, please use expo-cli doctor instead
```

This seems circular, or at least fishy. I have the latest `expo` and `expo-cli` installed, but I'm still being told to install something else (more recent).

How do I fix this so I'm not being told to install something that (I think) I already have installed.

---

Anywhere:

```
$ npm list --location=global --depth=0
/opt/homebrew/lib
├── @aws-amplify/cli@10.7.3
├── corepack@0.16.0
├── create-expo-app@1.3.2
├── eas-cli@3.6.0
├── expo-cli@6.3.1
├── firebase-tools@11.23.1
├── ios-sim@9.0.0
├── npm-check-updates@16.7.5
├── npm@9.5.0
└── react-devtools@4.27.2
$ which -a eas
/opt/homebrew/bin/eas
$ eas --version
eas-cli/3.6.0 darwin-arm64 node-v18.14.1
$ expo --version
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
6.3.1
```

In my project directory:

```
$ yarn list
...
├── expo-dev-client@2.0.1
├── expo-file-system@15.1.1
├── expo-sharing@11.0.1
├── expo-splash-screen@0.17.5
├── expo-status-bar@1.4.4
├── expo-updates@0.15.6
├── expo@47.0.13
$ which -a expo
/private/var/folders/90/46v8ldy13r13wf1hr7w9xzfw0000gn/T/xfs-08dd5804/expo
/opt/homebrew/bin/expo
$ /private/var/folders/90/46v8ldy13r13wf1hr7w9xzfw0000gn/T/xfs-08dd5804/expo
-bash: /private/var/folders/90/46v8ldy13r13wf1hr7w9xzfw0000gn/T/xfs-08dd5804/expo: No such file or directory
...
```

At `~`:

```
$ npm list
/Users/Rax
└── (empty)
$ yarn list
yarn list v1.22.19
Done in 0.01s.
$ which -a expo
/opt/homebrew/bin/expo
```

Comment: Possibly also causing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75439948/656912).

Answer (score -1):

You need to do exactly what error message states. Instead of running `expo-cli` you need to use `npx expo`, it will use locally installed(in your project) version of the expo cli that is tied to the version of expo package in your project.

Note that expo doctor is not implemented in local cli, so that command is always using global one.

Comment: That's not the case. I have the correct versions installed. It's just a [bad error message](https://forums.expo.dev/t/why-am-i-told-to-install-versioned-expo-cli-when-its-already-installed/69654/2?u=orome) (about the node version I'm using).

Comment: No, message is correct, but it might be misleading. Global expo-cli does not support node 17+ and because doctor is not implemented in local cli, so it's using implementation from the global one. Based on what you provided above, you are using node 18 which is not compatible with the old global cli, so you don't have "correct" version installed.

Comment: It's both, but more incorrect than misleading since the instructions on how to remedy are wrong. (Also Node 18 should be supported if the documentation is the be believed, since it's LTS.)